# node.js adding new export field without braking existing requires

Tags: node.js

Consider following simple scenario, file config.js:

```
const config = {
  a: '123'
}

module.exports = config;
```

and it's usage:

```
const cfg = require('./conifg');
console.log(cfg.a);
```

Now I'm in need to add additional export member to config.js:

```
const config = {
  a: '123'
}

function someFunction() {
  console.log('blah');
}

module.exports = {
  config,
  someFunction
};
```

This modification brakes down so-far working code, because `cfg.a` in

```
const cfg = require('./conifg');
console.log(cfg.a);
```

points now to `undefined`.

Is there any way to extend `module.exports` while remaining it's "default" exported member to not brake things down?

Answer (score 1):

you may export all property of config separately

```
module.exports = {
  ...config,
  someFunction
};
```

---

or if you don't want use spread, you can access by

```
const cfg = require('./conifg');
console.log(cfg.config.a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
const config = {
  a: '123',
  someFunction: someFunction
}

function someFunction() {
  console.log('blah');
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, semantically it would be horrible, config is huge JSON with texts mostly, when out of sudden function occupies one of fields... but hey, thanks for help :)